# Register user controls (ascx) in web.config?

Tags: user-controls, web-config

Since `ASP.NET` 2.0 I usually register reusable user controls in `web.config`, rather then register it in every page with `<%@ Register %>` directives.

**UPDATED** See [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config) for what I mean.

Is there any "Sharepoint way" to do it for Sharepoint (2010/2013) development?

Comment: Can you use web parts?

Comment: `User control` is shared between `_layouts` and `rendering control`

Answer (score 2):

While developing for SharePoint 2010/2013 using Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013, Microsoft provides an excellent integration to package third-party assemblies and safe control entries via package designer.

Package designer not only helps you with packaging you SharePoint solutions but also allows you to add the assembly references, **SafeControl** entries and user controls.

Think twice before fiddling and manipulating web.config via `SPWebConfigModification`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

create your user control

then add to masterpage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix=”myUserControl” TagName=”myUserControlPage” Src=”~/_controltemplates/myUserControlFolder/myUserControlPage.ascx” %>
```

now all you need todo is add the control to where ever you want using this:

```
<myUserControl:myUserControlPage ID=”myUserControl” runat=”server” />
```

very simple solution! just like how layouts and masterpage works!

Comment: Interesting, what's the overhead?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allenwang/archive/2012/05/21/modify-web-config-file-dynamically-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) is the best way to do it.

You can programmatically modify the web config on feature activated/deactivated to maintain and update whatever web config is being used when you activate your feature. Keep in mind the scope of your feature however.

[A few more options](http://www.firozozman.com/post/5-ways-to-update-Sharepoint-WebConfig-file.aspx) but I don't suggest manual updating.

Answer (score 0):

I already created different custom user control that I use in different web part or application page.

1. Open Visual Studio and create an Empty SharePoint Project
2. Right click on the project item and add a user control, visual studio creates different folder and files
3. Write your code
4. Publish (create a wsp file)
5. Deploy it on your farm.

The control is stored under the following folder C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\Your_Project_Name\User_Control_Name.ascx

And then you can use it on your web page using

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="yourprefix" Src="/_controltemplates/15/Your_Project_Name/User_Control_Name.ascx" TagName="yourtagname" %>
```

Comment: It's **not** about creating custom user control, it's about **reusing existing** one without the need to register it in every page/control.